# Is there a faster alternative to the HT12E / HT12D IC?

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, encoder, timing, emitter

I am looking for a quicker alternative to the HT12E encoder IC.

This IC lets you encode 8 bits of adresse and 4 bits of data. Once the bits are encoded, it outputs a frame containing all those bits like so: 
[image]

My problem is that each frame is always sent 4 times. You then obtain this signal each time you want to communicate through the RF emitter :

[image]

The timing becomes a serious problem with the delay between two different set of four frames :

[image]

So, am I doing something wrong? 
To reduce delays, I used the highest resistor value as told in the datasheet : 470kOhms for a frequency of ~7,75KHz (page 9).

If everything seems fine, could anyone advise me for another IC? I only need 2 or 3 adresse bits, and at least four data beats. It would be great if there wouldn't be more than 200ms between to different frames.

HT12E datasheet : https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1899539.pdf

Thanks a lot in avance and good luck for those crazy times. And also sorry for my English.

Comment: This would be a relatively trivial task for any microcontroller. Perhaps and Arduino or a bare AVR IC with the Arduino OS programmed.  Or (gasp) machine code) or ... . If you can tolerate a total of 8 bits then many UART ICs may be suitable.

Comment: Digikey in stock 8 bit total [here](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/TXII/TXIIS06568/TXIIS06568-1.pdf?hkey=EC6BD57738AE6E33B588C5F9AD3CEFA7) and [here](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/PHGL/PHGLS14341/PHGLS14341-1.pdf?hkey=EC6BD57738AE6E33B588C5F9AD3CEFA7) - I'd use a microcontroller.

Comment: Hi Russel! Thanks for you answer, I'm quite new in electronics, and I have a very limited knowledge about what is available to work with. Now that you told me about those UART ICs I have more question if you don't mind. The project is : 
A smartphone app communicate through bluetooth with a mother module which contains a UC. The uC process the frame that comes from the phone and distribute the instructions to all the concerned child modules via RF. 
I thought that putting a uC in each module would be overkilled, and that's why i went for the encoder/decoder. 
What do you think? 
Thks again

Comment: There will be other encoder ICs BUT a uC is not vastly dearer and gives you complete flexibility. You can buy a uC with hardware UART (parallel to serial converter) built in - but coding what you ant in an AVR or ARDUINO is a relatively simple tas AND there will be library functions top do so. Smaller AVRs sell for less tah the encoder IC. A crystal is a good idea (not essential probably).

Comment: Thanks a lot Russel ! Those were precious advices, I am going to study the options I have concerning those AVR
Thanks again
Théo